# getSupportActionBar() return null

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I am using `Support Actionbar`. It is working on in `MessageTemplateActivity` because when I want to show back enable as `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`, it is enabling back button. But in `SyncActivity`, `getSupportActionBar() is returning`null`. Can anyone please tell me why in`SyncActivity` it returns null.

### NullPointerException

```
06-17 18:45:45.327: E/AndroidRuntime(25335): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 18:45:45.327: E/AndroidRuntime(25335):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.getDisplayOptions(ActionBarImplICS.java:234)
06-17 18:45:45.327: E/AndroidRuntime(25335):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.<init>(ActionBarImplICS.java:57)
06-17 18:45:45.327: E/AndroidRuntime(25335):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.<init>(ActionBarImplICS.java:46)
06-17 18:45:45.327: E/AndroidRuntime(25335):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.createSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:46)
06-17 18:45:45.327: E/AndroidRuntime(25335):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:83)
06-17 18:45:45.327: E/AndroidRuntime(25335):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivity.java:66)
```

### SyncActivity.java

```
public class SyncActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_sync_activity);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

### layout_sync_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainSyncScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

### MessageTemplateActivity.java

```
public class MessageTemplateActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_message_template);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

### layout.layout_message_template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks,